# How do you turn an ndarray::ArrayView into a new ndarray?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

How do you efficiently take a view of an `ndarray` and create a new `ndarray` from it, like `array[1..5, 3..6]`?

Comment: You mean an owned `Array`?

Comment: I've got an owned `ndarray::Array2`. I'd like to select a rectangle within it and use that to create a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs of `ArrayBase`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#conversions-between-array-types) have a nice conversion table. The way to convert from `ArrayView` and `ArrayViewMut` to `Array` is [`view.to_owned()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.to_owned).

To slice an owned array into an owned array, though, have a more efficient implementation: [`slice_move()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.slice_move) or [`slice_collapse()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.slice_collapse).

Comment: But how do you use this to slice. E.g., take only a portion of the original, owned array and turn it into a new, owned array?

Comment: @Test Simply: you slice the array then convert the view into a method. However, as I note in the answer there is a more efficient method.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Can you give an example of calling `slice_move`?

Comment: @Test `array.slice_move(s![1..5, 3..6])`.